# Enable NCCL in Custom TensorFlow Build

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, nvlink

I am building TF 2.5.2 from source, how can I enable NCCL during the build? I have NCCL built, as well as having cuDNN and CUDA 8 (i.e., I am on the build config phase). --config=nccl doesn't work. I know that --config=nonccl is a default, so how do I avoid implementing it?

I tried to build TF from source, and it is working really well. But I can't figure out how to include NCCL utilization!